# Dynamics 365: Create popup with table and search bar

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am attempting to create popup that appears when a ribbon button is clicked on a record.
The goal is that when a "Qualify" ribbon button is clicked on the "Lead" record, a popup will appear that has a search bar to look up "Account" records to see if the account already exists.

I have looked into the Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog() method, but it doesn't seem like there is a way to add a search/table to the popup. Also looked some into the openForm() method, but that doesn't seem too useful in this situation.

I am still fairly new to D365 so I'm not exactly sure what the best way to create something like this would be, so any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated. I would prefer to do this without HTML, however I feel like it might be necessary for something like this to work?

Comment: Are you using Dynamics CRM online?

Comment: Yes, but I am doing this through a Ribbon Button using the Ribbon Workbench, so still Javascript and HTML

Comment: You can create a Canvas App and pass the parameters OnClick event of ribbon button.